# Submitted If statement undefined error

Tags: php

I have a problem with the following: if ($_POST['Submitted'] == "true") { This line keeps producing an undefined error "Undefined index: Submitted in C:\wamp\www\oop_settings\index.php on line 13

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    ob_start();

    include_once ("includes/settings.php");
    include("includes/functions/functions.php");
    //include_once ("includes/optional.php");

    var_dump($_POST);// Sanity check

  if ($_POST['Submitted'] == "true") {
    $Errors = "";
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = false;
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = "";
    $_SESSION['UserAdmin'] = false;

    // process submitted data
    $userSQL = $Database->Execute("SELECT UserID, UserFullname, UserEmail, UserLastPassword FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Text->ValidSQLString($_POST['Username'])) . "' AND UserPassword = '" . md5($_POST['Password']) . "' AND UserActive = 1 AND UserListingOnly = 0 AND UserID NOT IN (61)");
     $UserCount = $Database->RecordCount($userSQL);
//echo $userSQL;

    if ($UserCount == 1) {
        // user found
        $rowUser = $Database->Records($userSQL);
        $LastMonth = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, (date("m") - 1), date("d"), date("Y")));

        if ($rowUser['UserLastPassword'] <= $LastMonth) {
            // password expired, generate new password
            $Errors = "Your password has expired, your new password has been sent to your inbox.";
            $NewPassword = $Text->ResetPassword();

            $userpasswordSQL = "UPDATE Users SET UserPassword = '" . md5($NewPassword) . "', UserLastPassword = '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' WHERE UserID = " . $rowUser['UserID'];
            $dbUserPassword = $Database->Execute($userpasswordSQL) or die ("New Password Query Failed: " . mysql_error());

            mail($rowUser['UserEmail'], "Watkins Hire - Your New Password", "Your old password has expired for security reasons.\n\nYour new password is: $NewPassword", "From: password@watkinshire.co.uk");
        }// end UserCount


    }//end if
}//end if

else {
            // valid log in
            $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $rowUser['UserID'];
            LoginForm(); // call the form function

}// end else if

?>
```

Comment: At least you should check whether it's set or not (with `isset($_POST['Submitted'])`).

Answer (score 0):

The POST request does not have the index "Submitted", which is why PHP tells you that it is undefined.

Like commented, you should check for its existence by testing it with `isset()` first, and then validate the value of this index.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply I have used the following code and seems to work.if (isset($_POST['Submitted']) && ($_POST['Submitted'] == 'true')) {}

Answer (score 0):

That's because it doesn't exist yet. Use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) if you simply need it to be set, or [`!empty()`](http://www.php.net/empty) if you want to make sure the value isn't an empty string, `0` or `null` before checking the value.:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submitted']) && $_POST['Submitted'] == "true") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your form submit name the `$_POST['submitted']` - `submitted` should be the name of your submit name

For eg:

```
<form>
 <input type="submit" name="submitted">
</form>
```

it should be some thing like this..............